# What is the algorithm for reading computerized text and handwritten numeric text from a tabular image using Python?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science-model, ocr

[image]

I want to read this image text

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Are you interested in [training a model yourself for this specific case of OCR](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-ocr-ee1469a201aa) or looking for a [pre-trained software](https://irisdatacapture.com/pt_solution/hybrid-forms-processing/) or library?